# TFS 2013 Dashboard contributor graph like in github

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Is there a way to show a graph of repository contributors in TFS 2013 dashboard like github shows as shown here : [About Repository Graphs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-graphs/)

ETA: I need graph for TFVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 will offer something like that in the IDE as part of [Code Lens when you're using a Git repository](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/04/29/what-s-new-in-codelens-for-visual-studio-2015-rc.aspx).

[image]

For TFVC it's possible to construct a report like this based on the Code Churn dimension in the data warehouse, but there is no out-of-the-box report that visualizes the changes and contributions in a ready to use dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, i would like to know more about Code Churn option, is it possible to somehow include this in tfs (for tfvc) dashboard (web based) of a project ?

Comment: It can be created on the SQL Server Report portal, if it has been configured for your TFS Instance. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244661.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: i can access SQL Server Report portal, but what do you mean configured for TFS instance ? If i have a report created that i need what are the steps to include it into a project dashboard ?

Comment: All guidance around creating and uploading custom reports can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649552.aspx

Comment: Thank you for all your help, will try this soon, and will accept as answer if i get desired results.

Comment: I managed to get it shown in excel and Uploaded it into SQL Server Report portal, now how can i show that report in Web Team Access dashboard ?

Comment: No, you cannot do that last bit. You can do it on the SharePoint portal, if you're using SharePoint with TFS, but not in Web Access.